# Can I specify an image/picture when setting the marker style of a line with markers chart in python-pptx?

Tags: python-3.x, python-pptx

I am trying to automate generating powerpoint charts for reports. I need to create lines w/ markers using a specific .png as the marker style. Is there a way to do this through python-pptx?

I tried navigating the documentation, and other posts on stack but found no answers.

Comment: This looks like a tough one, Jose. But to try to solve it it'd be useful to know how you'd do it in the Powerpoint application. That would give us a clue as to the data model.

Comment: Hi Martin! I found that it is possible to change the marker style via python-pptx

E.g.:
series.marker.style = XL_MARKER_STYLE.CIRCLE

There is even an option to use XL_MARKER_STYLE.PICTURE but beyond that, no option to specify which picture to use.

Comment: However, to change it through the application, one can right click the series on the chart -> Format Data Series -> Go to Markers -> Marker Options -> Built-in -> change Type to Picture and then select from directory.

Comment: That's an advance, Jose. The next step, I'm afraid, is to dump the XML from inside the .pptx. That way we can see what elements and attributes to add/modify. I don't know if you're up for that. To be honest I've not worked with charts inside PowerPoint with Python-pptx YET.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.